# Github pages deploy Next.js assetPrefix not working

Tags: next.js, github-pages

i am having problems deploying a gh-pages branch which is generated by `next build && next export`, my repo name is `portfolio` so the generated url is http://blackshot.github.io/portfolio/ i been reading that using `assetPrefix` and `basePath` works but not for me.

though this is my `next.config.js`

```js
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
module.exports = {
    basePath: isDev ? "": "/portfolio",
    assetPrefix: isDev ? "": "/portfolio/"
}
```

browser is still 404ing assets
[image: 404ing]

[blackshot/portfolio](https://github.com/blackshot/portfolio/tree/gh-pages) is the repo if you want to take a look

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: It turns out that I was using `next-image` plugin and it have to be configured separately.
https://nicedoc.io/twopluszero/next-images

Answer (score 0):

As @Свободен said

When using **next-image** we should set the assetPrefix inside it.

```js
const withImages = require('next-images')
const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

module.exports = withPlugins([
    [withImages, {
        assetPrefix: isDev ? "": "/repository_name/"
    }],
    {
        trailingSlash: true,
        basePath: isDev ? "": "/repository_name",
        assetPrefix: isDev ? "": "/repository_name/"    
    }
])
```

Comment: i'll check this, a soon as i can, thanks for answering!